# unable to have a has a relation

Tags: c++, class, object

```
#ifndef IMAGEDATA_H
#define IMAGEDATA_H

#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

class ImageData {
public:
    std::string foo;
    std::string bar;
private:
};

#endif
```

I have this class definition and I have another class which has one of this class as follows:

```
#ifndef UserImageCollection_H
#define UserImageCollection_H

#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include "ImageData.h"

class UserImageCollection
{
public:
    std::string uid;
    std::string guid;
    std::string data;
    std::string vector<ImageData> imageData;
private:
};

#endif
```

when i make the file, I get this error:

```
In file included from UserImageCollection.cc:1:
../../include/producer/UserImageCollection.h:12: error: expected `;' before '<' token
gmake: *** [UserImageCollection.o] Error 1
```

in my UserImageCollection.cc file there is only 1 line right now.

When i comment out

```
std::string vector<ImageData> imageData;
```

it compiles but i need it, how can i get it running?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`imageData` cannot be both a `std::string` and `std::vector<ImageData>`.

It must be:

```
std::string imageData;
```

or:

```
std::vector<ImageData> imageData;
```